# media_handle_upload fails with gravity form submitted image

Tags: php, plugin-gravity-forms, uploads

Been stuck on this for a while now --
This function stopped working on a site I maintain recently, and I'm not sure exactly why. It is failing at the first media_handle_upload function and gives me this error:

```
Array([error] => Specified file failed upload test.
```

Tried using this code instead of media_handle_upload,
https://gist.github.com/hissy/7352933 , but in with the code from the gist I got this error:

```
017/05/17 05:45:59 [error] 2066#2066: *10499 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/tmp/php8mjcrC): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/test.dev/current/web/app/themes/test/functions.php on line 1083
```

Here is my function. It is hooking into a Gravity Forms form that accepts user submitted photos. I want these to be auto-populated in the media library. It used to work, I'm not sure what broke it, potentially something in WordPress v4.7

```
add_action("gform_pre_submission_16", "post_submission");

function post_submission(){
    $body = 'From: '.$_POST['input_2'];
    $body .= '<br/>Email: '.$_POST['input_3'];
    $body .= '<br/>Description: '.$_POST['input_5'];

    $mypostID = 0; // change it to your desired post id

    $photo_description = $_POST['input_5'];

    $photo_credit = $_POST['input_2'];

    if( !empty($_FILES['input_13']['name'])) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
        $attach_id = media_handle_upload('input_13', $mypostID);
        $strain_cat_id = $_POST['input_20'];
        $cat_id = $_POST['input_21'];

        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, $strain_cat_id, 'media_category', true );
        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, $cat_id, 'media_category', true );
        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, 170, 'media_category', true );
        $my_post = array(
            'ID'           => $attach_id,
            'post_content' => $photo_description
            );

        wp_update_post( $my_post );

        update_post_meta( $attach_id, 'photo_credit', $photo_credit );
        $body .= '<br/><a href="http://darkheartnursery.com/wp-admin/upload.php?item='.$attach_id.'">View Photo for '.$strain_cat_id.'</a>';
    }


    if( !empty($_FILES['input_14']['name']) ) {

        $attach_id = media_handle_upload('input_14', $mypostID);

        $strain_cat_id = $_POST['input_22'];

        $cat_id = $_POST['input_26'];

        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, $strain_cat_id, 'media_category', true );
        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, $cat_id, 'media_category', true );
        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, 170, 'media_category', true );

        $my_post = array(
            'ID'           => $attach_id,
            'post_content' => $photo_description
            );

        wp_update_post( $my_post );

        update_post_meta( $attach_id, 'photo_credit', $photo_credit );

        $body .= '<br/><a href="http://darkheartnursery.com/wp-admin/upload.php?item='.$attach_id.'">View Photo for '.$strain_cat_id.'</a>';

    }
    if( !empty($_FILES['input_15']['name']) ) {

        $attach_id = media_handle_upload('input_15', $mypostID);

        $strain_cat_id = $_POST['input_23'];

        $cat_id = $_POST['input_27'];

        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, $strain_cat_id, 'media_category', true );
        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, $cat_id, 'media_category', true );
        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, 170, 'media_category', true );

        $my_post = array(
            'ID'           => $attach_id,
            'post_content' => $photo_description
            );

        wp_update_post( $my_post );

        update_post_meta( $attach_id, 'photo_credit', $photo_credit );

        $body .= '<br/><a href="http://darkheartnursery.com/wp-admin/upload.php?item='.$attach_id.'">View Photo for '.$strain_cat_id.'</a>';

    }
    if( !empty($_FILES['input_16']['name']) ) {

        $attach_id = media_handle_upload('input_16', $mypostID);

        $strain_cat_id = $_POST['input_24'];

        $cat_id = $_POST['input_28'];

        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, $strain_cat_id, 'media_category', true );
        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, $cat_id, 'media_category', true );
        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, 170, 'media_category', true );

        $my_post = array(
            'ID'           => $attach_id,
            'post_content' => $photo_description
            );

        wp_update_post( $my_post );

        update_post_meta( $attach_id, 'photo_credit', $photo_credit );

        $body .= '<br/><a href="http://darkheartnursery.com/wp-admin/upload.php?item='.$attach_id.'">View Photo for '.$strain_cat_id.'</a>';

    }
    if( !empty($_FILES['input_17']['name']) ) {

        $attach_id = media_handle_upload('input_17', $mypostID);

        $strain_cat_id = $_POST['input_25'];

        $cat_id = $_POST['input_29'];

        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, $strain_cat_id, 'media_category', true );
        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, $cat_id, 'media_category', true );
        wp_set_object_terms( $attach_id, 170, 'media_category', true );

        $my_post = array(
            'ID'           => $attach_id,
            'post_content' => $photo_description
            );

        wp_update_post( $my_post );

        update_post_meta( $attach_id, 'photo_credit', $photo_credit );

    }
}
```

Really appreciate any help or guidance on this. I can provide more clarity or code if needed as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That error is very probabbly due to incorrect loading of the required files from wp-admin; note how in your code those files are loaded only when a scpecific input has data (`input_13`) but not in every case you need those files.

You do this:

```
if( !empty($_FILES['input_13']['name'])) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    // ....
}
```

So, if `$_FILES['input_13']['name']` is empty, the rest of code that needs those files from wp-admin will fail.

Try to include the required files with a more appropiate logic.

Comment: This isn't the issue. That code was definitely executing correctly. To make sure I took out the if statement and left the code inside, and still got this error when I print_r my variable $attach_id:  `Array([error] => Specified file failed upload test.`

Comment: Can you post the HTML form you are using to upload the files?

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out why I file_get_contents couldn't access /tmp, however I figured out a workaround. I used the gform_after_submission action, and  pulled the file from the gravity forms uploads directory. Using media_handle_sideload I was able to import it into the media library and apply the necessary metadata.